# Div is not created before javascript run

Tags: javascript, onload, classname

I have a question about javascript/html.

First, I have this:

```
var post = document.body.getElementsByClassName("post");  
var x=post[i].getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].innerHTML;
```

I get from the debugger that `x` is **not defined**, it doesn't exists.

This javascript function runs `onload` of the body. I am sure that I gave the right classnames in my javascript, so it should find my div.

So, I read somewhere that sometimes javascript does not find an element because it **is not yet there**, it is not yet created in the browser ( whatever that means).

Is it possible that my function can't find the div with that classname because of this reason?

Is there a solution?

Comment: You should provide us your HTML code to get better help!

Comment: Format your code when asking a question, and include a full though minimal working illustration of your issue.

Comment: Make sure that your browser supports `document.getElementByClassName()` also you're passing `0` node values in `var x` but you didn't even include it in `var post`. Also, as @Dr.Molle has pointed out, `i` has no business there. You should also add event listeners like jQuery's `.ready()` function in the case that the browser is reading the `div` before it's reading the javascript.

Comment: First of all, of course i care about my question. from the first moment i saw the answer i try to put my html code but i couldn't, i am new and i don't know how does this works.

Secondly, i is a variable tha a for loop uses to access all posts in the body. So i is ok.

I didn't quite understand what you said about 0 node ModerDesigner.

Can I add jQuery's ready functions in my javascript code? How? thank you all.

Comment: @Vlenorroia format your last comment into your question. And never mind about you not passing a node value on your first query. I realized it's not needed in that instance. And of course you can do it with jQuery. I'll post an answer showing how to do it in jQuery.

Comment: *"Secondly, i is a variable tha a for loop uses to access all posts in the body. So i is ok."* And how can anyone know this from looking at your question. It's a great disservice when people upvote "questions" like this.

Comment: ...if the debugger says `x` is not defined, then there's some issue that's not present in the tiny bit you provided.

Comment: Now it gives me uncaught error initialization is not defined even when I use jQuery. It cannot find the function. What can possibly be the problem? I have this: I declare my js file like this:
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"src="localhost:8080/ituned.com/JavaScriptFiles/…; In my html code: <body onLoad="initialization()"> Javascript inside my js file : $(document).ready(function initialization() { blah blah }); this is my code jsfiddle.net/bhPnC . debugger gives that initialization is not defined and also that this line var post = document.body.getElementsByClassName("post

Comment: There's no need to call `initialization()` after you have immediately invoked a function. Just use `$(document).ready(function() { });` That takes `initialization()` out of the picture altogether. If that still doesn't work, do try my pure javascript way using `window.onload` That should definitely work.

Comment: Also, you posted an answer. This would be an appropriate comment, or if you needed more room, just make an "edit" section in your original question.

Comment: -- this is my code http://jsfiddle.net/bhPnC/ . debugger gives that initialization is not defined and also that this line var post = document.body.getElementsByClassName("post") which is inside the javascript function produces null object "post".

Comment: I updated your fiddle, and it should work. The reason why `initialization()` is undefined, is you are defining `initialization()` inside of a `$(document).ready()` expression, which won't work. It needs to be just `function` with no name, then remove the body onload expression. The reason why you're getting `JavaScript function produces null object "post"` is because you aren't passing any node values `document.body.getElementsByClassName("post")[0]` notice the `[0]` Here's is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhPnC/1/

Comment: Ok, good work with the initialization, i don't have a problem with that anymore. but i still get an undefined object. What do you mean i do not pass any node values? What is the problem with these lines :  var post = document.body.getElementsByClassName("post");  ......  post[i].getElementsByClassName("styled")[1].style.position='relative'; ---error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Because that's an equivalent to `document.body.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].getElementsByClassName("styled")[1].style.position = 'relative'` which, obviously, isn't gonna work. Try this, though I'm not sure if it'll work: http://jsfiddle.net/bhPnC/2/

Comment: No it does not work :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined post[i]

..I really don't understand why this document.body.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].getElementsByClassName("styled"‌​)[1].style.position = 'relative' does not work. if the div with that class exists, why can't it find?!

Comment: Try removing `.body.` just use `document.getElementsByClassName("post")`

Comment: Nothing changed, unfortunately..

Comment: strangely enough, it appears that only the 8th document.body.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].getElementsByClassName("styled"‌​)[0] is null.I can't understand why, because there are 10 objects in the html page.

Comment: Okay. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bhPnC/3/ I moved the `appearTextArea()` function inside the jQuery function. That may be what was wrong, because it wasn't parsing the same, original `post` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, instead of calling functions with
`body onload`, use jQuery's `ready()` function, or, if you don't want to use jQuery, you can use pure javascript, but this is up to you:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    var post = document.getElementsByClassName("post"),
    x = post[i].getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].innerHTML;
});

// JavaScript
window.onload = function initialization() {
    var post = document.getElementsByClassName("post"),
    x = post[i].getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

A few side notes, I don't know what the use of `innerHTML`
is, and also if you're doing a for loop with `i` then definitely
post that code, that's kind of important.

After some discussion, my answer seems to have worked for you, but you can also place your script at the end of your body tag as @RobG has suggested.

Comment: And make sure that the rest of your code is inside of the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: If you have an answer, please post an answer.  It seems the clarifications that comments are *supposed* to bring turned into a discussion about the merits of JQuery, and then devolved into near name-calling. Please refrain from extended discussions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I read somewhere that sometimes javascript does not find an element because it is not yet there, it is not yet created in the browser ( whatever that means).

Browsers create the DOM progressively as they get the markup. When a script element is encountered, all processing of the markup stops (except where [defer and async](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/tabular.html#defer) have an effect) while the script is run. If the script attempts to access an element that hasn't been created yet (probably because its markup hasn't been processed yet) then it won't be found.

> This javascript function runs onload of the body.

If that means you are using something like:

```
<body onload="someFn()"...>
```

or perhaps

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    someFn();
    ...
  }
</script>
```

then when the function is called, all DOM nodes are available. Some, like images, may not be fully loaded, but their elements have been created.

If it means you have the script in the body and aren't using the `load` event, you should move the script to the bottom of the page (e.g. just before the closing `body` tag) and see if that fixes the issue.